# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in line3

Tags: php, mysql

error in line 3: that begin by $sql

```
<?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `sub_id` FROM `subject_studant` WHERE `std_id` = 2 ") or die    mysql error();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    { 
        $sub_id1 = $row['sub_id'];
        echo $sub_id1; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated and the function name is mysql_error without spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing an underscore. mysql_error() is a function name, which contains an underscore.